# How to deploy SpringBoot project on Heroku?

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, deployment, heroku-postgres

My SpringBoot project consists of several modules. This is an example project structure:

```
---Application(packaging pom)
--------Main A(packaging jar)   
--------Module B(packaging jar)
--------Module C(packaging jar)
   pom.xml
```

Module A is the main. It has only one class that runs the project(SpringBootApplication).
Other modules just use each other's dependencies.The module A uses the dependencies of all other modules.

How can I set up the project correctly so that I can deploy to Heroku if the SpringBootApplication in the Module A?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Maven project (i.e. sub-module) as a Maven option by running:

```
$ heroku config:set MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS="-pl Main"
```